# How to handle business logic and Android string resources inside Kotlin data classes?

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture, business-logic, data-class

Is there a recommended practice on how to handle the business logic inside a Kotlin Data class?
For eg: I have a DTO object thats coming from a REST API like this:

```
data class ResponseDTO(
    @SerializedName("isAuto") val isAuto: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("autoStatus") val autoStatus: String
) {
    fun getStatus() : String {
        if (isAuto) {
            if (autoStatus.isNotEmpty()) {
                return autoStatus
            } else {
                return "Default Auto"
            }
        }
        else {
            return "Default Manual"
        }
    }
}
```

We need to return different Strings based on the values returned so what are the best practices to

1. Define the business logic inside the Kotlin data class
2. Get the string resources inside the Kotlin data class

This is only an example and not the exact code but our API is returning basic values and we have lot of Business logic to deduce what we want to display in the UI.

Comment: you need to create viewModel where you should apply your business logics after getting data from Api

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the data classes (transfer objects) from the ones that implement business logic, because they change for different reasons.

Thus I would create a class that takes the transfer object (maybe an interface of the transfer object) as it's argument. E.g.

```
// I'm not very good in Kotlin so I will use Java here.
// I guess you'll find better names

public interface Data { 
   public Boolean isAuto();
   public String getAutoStatus();
}
   
public class SomeGoodName {
    private Data data;
    
    public SomeGoodName(Data data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus(){
       if(data.isAuto()){
            if (autoStatus.isNotEmpty()) {
                return data.getAutoStatus()
            } else {
                return "Default Auto"
            }
       } else {
            return "Default Manual"
       }
    }
}
```

The transfer object can then implement the `Data` interface.

Comment: Thanks, how do we get the string resources from `SomeGoodName` class?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
enum class Default {
  AUTO,MANUAL;
  
  fun getStringMessage(context:Context): String {
    val res = context.resources
    return when(this){
       AUTO -> res.getString(R.string.auto)
       MANUAL-> res.getString(R.string.manual)
    }
  }
}

data class ResponseDTO(
    @SerializedName("isAuto") val isAuto: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("autoStatus") val autoStatus: String
) {
    fun getStatus() : Default {
        if (isAuto) {
            if (autoStatus.isNotEmpty()) {
                return autoStatus
            } else {
                return Default.AUTO
            }
        }
        else {
            return Default.MANUAL
        }
    }
}
```

in `activity` or `fragment` or `viewModel`

```
...
val defaultMessage = ResponseDTO(
    isAuto = true,
    autoStatus = "somthing"
).getStatus().getStringMessage(context)
...
```

Comment: So basically we are pushing the responsibility to another class. But I am not sold on creating an enum for each string resource which I feel is an overhead.

Comment: Another way is passing context as parameter in your data class `getStatus(context:Context)` , but that would be pain if you want to call get status inside another class , and one thing , instead of creating an enum for each , why not just wrap it in a single enum called `Respons` ??